# Brute force detector using Notify option

Tags: php, security, brute-force

I am trying to write some code to prevent Brute force attack on my website so I just got to know some of the tricks that I can use. So I just write these code in config.php which are:

**1. Enabling anti-attack**
It is time-out value which sleeps for particular time when it detects Brute force attack.

```
    // if set to 1, sleep the application for several minutes, causing attackers' tools
    timing out
    $anti_attack = 0;
    $sleep_time = 5; // minute
```

But then I come to know that by this code it may cause DOS to my website so I just got to know one more trick but I am not able to write it that is:

**2. Modify notify option**
: I am not able to run this because it is giving some sort of error. To prevent this I started writing and able to make only one syntax that is :

```
    $emailnotify = 1;
    // rest I am not able to
```

So is there any special syntax which I can use to  modify notification option using PHP.

Comment: Even though you add a sleep, the server still receives a request. It just waits to perform it. So overflow is still possible. 

A more efficient method is going to be to send a command to either iptables, or even better to send a command to your external firewall to block the request completely.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_BruteForce_Attack_Detector

Comment: https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-57619-post-57641.html#pid57641

Comment: Please try to understand the question i want to modify notify option which i am not able to do and @Epik well you said right but i just wanted to make it much secure by php coding.

Comment: @ShashankSharma To be honest i believe adding PHP code that accepts the request is going to hurt more than help. There is absolutely no benefit doing what you're doing as any script that sees it will still get the accepted headers and wait for the response, or even worse keep requesting over and over. It will make no difference if you sleep on the response. 

Further more, your code and question is very unclear.

Comment: Please be more specific about what software you use and what you are really trying to archive. Your answer is to vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After actually 3 weeks I finally got the answer with some research and I got this which is quite working. The answers mention above mine are also quite correct but actually I was just trying to do something unique and wanted to learn new things.

Here is the code for **Modify notify option.**

---

```
$emailnotify = 1;
//Log attacks in file, 1 to yes, 0 to no
$logfile = 1;
//Log attacks in system log mechanism or server, 1 to yes,
//0 to no
$logsys = 0;
// if set to 1, sleep the application for several minutes
$anti_attack = 0;
$sleep_time = 5; 
//minute
```

Answer (score -1):

You are addressing the problem at the wrong layer. You need to stop the request at the webserver level, because by sleeping, your PHP process will still consume memory and therefore you can quickly get DOS'ed out of memory.

**If you want to do this correctly, then add a rate limit to your firewall.**

If you want to saveguard long running operations, then you can write a lock file (or better use the semaphore module). Then you can sleep to get your webserver cycle out of workers. Your page will be inaccessible them. I am sure that is not what you really want.

Comment: I want to do modify notify option ... or else i know much higher security tricks that I can do but doing modify notify option is new to me and i want to explore all these things ... so is there any answer you can give. Your answer is going to another path.

Comment: As I have not idea of what software you are trying to use and what you actually want to archive, I cannot help you. Please modify your questions such that it is specific.